# How to Install Prism Module

Tags: installation

[Prism.js](https://prismjs.com/) is a useful syntax highlighter that is good for displaying code samples on web pages.

I have installed the [Prism](https://www.drupal.org/project/prism) module, and I have followed all of the instructions in the module's README.txt file. When publishing an article node with the following HTML, the resulting web page does not include the syntax highlighting provided by `prism.js`.

What is the correct way to use prism syntax highlighting in Drupal?

```
[prism:css] 
    a { color: #7BC673; } 
    p a { color: #22272A; } 
    p a:hover { color: #7BC673; } 
[/prism:css]
```

Comment: What Drupal version? Are you using FULL HTML format?

Answer (score 1):

I've followed following steps and getting that `prism` works fine, you can verify your steps as below:

1. Install [Prism](https://www.drupal.org/project/prism) and [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module (*Libraries module is required by prism*).
2. Download prism.js and prism.css from [here](https://prismjs.com/download.html), then put both files in 'sites/all/libraries'. So, The library path should be like as follows:
   `sites/all/libraries/prism/prism.js`
   `sites/all/libraries/prism/prism.css`
   See screenshot:
   [image]
3. Check or Enable 'Prism (syntax highlight)' check box from `Full HTML` Text format configuration page (`admin/config/content/formats/full_html`) then click on the `Save Configuration` button to save changes.
4. Create a node/content with and put your css code in a field whose `Text Format` is `Full HTML`.
   [image]
   Output/Result (though it includes `<br>` but it can be removed by configure text format):
   [image]